# Inserting PHP variable string into inline string doesn't work as it should

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am a bit rusted in PHP and currently struggling to do something that should be quite simple.

```
$value = "PUPPY";
$html .= '<td>{$value}</td>';
echo $html; // Doesn't work, prints {$value}.... Should be... PUPPY
```

I know there's a simple way for doing this but i just forgot and cannot find a definitive method on Google or StackOverflow.

I need to place the html in a variable cause once it is all done, it gets used by tcpdf::writeHtml()

I already tried :

```
$html .= "<td align='right' nowrap>".$value."</td>";
echo $html; // But this outputs a TD tag with attribute nowrap=""  and this is not valid HTML... tcpdf:writeHtml rejects this.
```

UPDATE: The bug was in fact caused by a bad usage of the "nowrap" attribute deprecated some time ago.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Single quoted strings are not interpolated in php. Use double quotes instead.

```
$value = "PUPPY";
$html .= "<td>{$value}</td>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell i already tried this (see update question above)... The problem is that it outputs invalid HTML.

Comment: there is no nowrap attribute for TD's in html maybe you mean `style='white-space:nowrap'`

Comment: It's an attribute generated by Adobe Dreamweaver so i figured it should be correctly expressed... I'll try to correct this.

Comment: It's deprecated... went out with html 4.1

Answer (score 6):

```
$value = "PUPPY";
$html .= "<td>{$value}</td>";
echo $html;
```

Use <kbd>"</kbd> instead of <kbd>'</kbd>

Take a look at the <kbd>[**documentation about Strings on PHP**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$html .= "<td>{$value}</td>";
```

Double quotes echo variables and single quotes do not.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `'<td>{$value}</td>'` put `"<td>{$value}</td>"`.

It should work fine